# search and add a pattern in a big file

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, awk

I have a big apache configuration file and in each of the virtualhost sections, I want to add its own log entry. I am wondering if I can do it with a script.

My current configuration file is something like this;

```
ServerName abc.com   
some information.   
…   
……
```

and I want to have it something like;

```
ServerName abc.com    
CustomLog "/usr/local/logs/abc.com.log"    
some information.    
…   
……
```

Is it possible by some sort of script? I have lots and lots of such virtualhost entries, so manually updating is impossible.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can be much simpler to use.

```
awk 'NR==3{print "my log"}1' INPUT_FILE
```

- `NR` is a built-in variable that tracks line numbers.
- You can also use `-v` and a `variable name` to pass values dynamically instead of hard-coding it in the script. eg. `awk -v line="$var" 'NR==line{print "my log"}1' INPUT_FILE`. In this case, `line` is an awk variable and `$var` can be your bash variable defined outside of `awk's` scope.

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
ServerName abc.com   
some information.   
…   
……  

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==3{print "my log"}1' file # add log after 2 lines
ServerName abc.com   
some information.   
my log
…   
……  

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==4{print "my log"}1' file # add log after 3 lines
ServerName abc.com   
some information.   
…   
my log
……  

[jaypal:~/Temp] var=2 # define a variable which holds the line number you want to print on
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v line="$var" 'NR==line{print "my log"}1' file
ServerName abc.com   
my log
some information.   
…   
……
```

In the comments I saw your question of adding your log after 3 lines starting from the matched pattern (ServerName, in this example). For that you can try something like this -

`awk '/ServerName/{a=NR;print;next} NR==(a+3){print$0;print "my log";next}1' file`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/ServerName/{a=NR;print;next} NR==(a+3){print$0;print "my log";next}1' file
ServerName abc.com   
some information.   
…   
……  
my log
```

Answer (score 5):

Sed will make quick work of this:

```
sed 's=^ServerName \(.*\)=&\nCustomLog "/usr/local/logs/\1.log"='
```

Edit: I previously posted something else, then went and test it and I had made a mistake.  So I tested choroba's answer, found that didn't quite work either, so fixed it and simplified it too.

Comment: Thank you for the help...however it is printing in the same line and not in the next line..

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment...that was bsd doing crap..it worked in linux.Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, say if i wish to add that custom log only after 3 lines after it finds the pattern servername , how do i do that ?

I will also highly appreciate if you can recommend any good tutorials on such commands... i like to know how to catch fish :) Thank you.

Comment: @Sangfroid You can use `awk` for that. I have added a solution that might help you resolve your question.

Comment: Thank you Jaypal. It worked with a minor tweak...By the way, which book do you suggest for such ?

Comment: @Sangfroid I would recommend this [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and this [guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this sed script:

```
sed -i~ '/^ServerName /s=^serverName \(.*\)=&\nCustomLog "/usr/local/logs/\1.log"=' config_file*
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of the answers worked for me when I tried them on my Mac for these reasons:

- sed requires `\` before opening and closing parenthesis for grouping
- Putting `\n` in replacement pattern just inserts an `n`.
- Bakkreference `\1` didn't work for `a` operation

Here is a command that worked:

```
sed -i.bak 's~^ServerName \(.*\)$~&\
CustomLog "/usr/local/logs/\1.log"~g' *.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds the desired line after 3 after the correct ServerName.

```
perl -i~ -ne'
   print;
   $target = $.+3 if /^\QServerName abc.com\E\s*$/;
   print qq{CustomLog "/usr/local/logs/abc.com.log"\n}
      if $target && $. == $target;
' apache.conf
```